# OpenGraph tags not rendering on NextJS application deployed on Vercel

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, facebook-opengraph, vercel

We have a NextJS application and we want to have OpenGraph preview on social sites with an image and snippet. We implemented it following [NextJS recommendations](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#opengraph):

`layout.js`

```js
import './globals.css'
import { Providers } from '@/components/providers'
import {
  GoogleTagManagerScript,
  GoogleTagManagerNoScript,
} from '@/components/analytics/GoogleTagManager'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Work In Ed',
  description: 'A new way to discover a job in teaching',
  openGraph: {
    title: 'Work In Ed',
    description: 'A new way to discover a job in teaching',
    url: 'https://workined.org/',
    images: 'https://d1lxsr6s25nfb5.cloudfront.net/images/38eb3e844473fb060c6901b74736910e.jpeg',
    type: 'website',
  },
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <GoogleTagManagerScript />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </head>
      <body id="__next">
        <GoogleTagManagerNoScript />
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

However, when I use [Facebook's OpenGraph checker](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fworkined.org), the HTML that's been seen it's just the core HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="__next_error__">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js" nomodule=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-1ede80e24acbf566.js" async=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/237-6d6f95ede2a81c01.js" async=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-app-9c3b1d2404e72bfa.js" async=""></script>
</body>
</html><html>
<script>(self.__next_f=self.__next_f||[]).push([0])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"0:\"$L1\"\n"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"2:I{\"id\":\"3110\",\"chunks\":[\"272:webpack-1ede80e24acbf566\",\"237:237-6d6f95ede2a81c01\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n4:I{\"id\":\"6436\",\"chunks\":[\"272:webpack-1ede80e24acbf566\",\"237:237-6d6f95ede2a81c01\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n5:I{\"id\":\"3277\",\"chunks\":[\"350:d24c7ea9-64bbad643742dcc8\",\"572:572-7b923d04b0416d9d\",\"161:161-ef79947ab3015ecc\",\"186:186-5c9d76b0b36326a9\",\"185:app/layout-ddf5d5769c07d250\"],\"name\":\"GoogleTagManagerScript\",\"async\":false}\n6:I{\"id\":\"3277\",\"chunks\":[\"350:d24c7ea9-64bbad643742dcc8\",\"572:572-7b92"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"3d04b0416d9d\",\"161:161-ef79947ab3015ecc\",\"186:186-5c9d76b0b36326a9\",\"185:app/layout-ddf5d5769c07d250\"],\"name\":\"GoogleTagManagerNoScript\",\"async\":false}\n7:I{\"id\":\"947\",\"chunks\":[\"350:d24c7ea9-64bbad643742dcc8\",\"572:572-7b923d04b0416d9d\",\"161:161-ef79947ab3015ecc\",\"186:186-5c9d76b0b36326a9\",\"185:app/layout-ddf5d5769c07d250\"],\"name\":\"Providers\",\"async\":false}\n8:I{\"id\":\"5706\",\"chunks\":[\"272:webpack-1ede80e24acbf566\",\"237:237-6d6f95ede2a81c01\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n9:I{\"id\":\"9556\",\"chunks\":[\"272:webpack-1ede"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"80e24acbf566\",\"237:237-6d6f95ede2a81c01\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\na:I{\"id\":\"3256\",\"chunks\":[\"350:d24c7ea9-64bbad643742dcc8\",\"572:572-7b923d04b0416d9d\",\"435:435-d82fda6aca2e1d3b\",\"161:161-ef79947ab3015ecc\",\"655:655-be78aa5ec6933203\",\"931:app/page-48ea47150ffc2d0a\"],\"name\":\"default\",\"async\":true}\n"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"1:[\"$\",\"$L2\",null,{\"assetPrefix\":\"\",\"initialCanonicalUrl\":\"/\",\"initialTree\":[\"\",{\"children\":[\"\",{}]},null,null,true],\"initialHead\":[\"$L3\",null],\"globalErrorComponent\":\"$4\",\"children\":[[\"$\",\"html\",null,{\"lang\":\"en\",\"children\":[[\"$\",\"head\",null,{\"children\":[[\"$\",\"$L5\",null,{}],[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"name\":\"viewport\",\"content\":\"initial-scale=1, width=device-width\"}]]}],[\"$\",\"body\",null,{\"id\":\"__next\",\"children\":[[\"$\",\"$L6\",null,{}],[\"$\",\"$L7\",null,{\"children\":[\"$\",\"$L8\",null,{\"parallelRouterKey\":\"children\",\"segmentPath\":[\"children\"],\"hasLoading\":false,\"template\":[\"$\",\"$L9\",null,{}],\"notFound\":[[\"$\",\"title\",null,{\"children\":\"404: This page could not be found.\"}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"style\":{\"fontFamily\":\"system-ui,\\\"Segoe UI\\\",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,\\\"Apple Color Emoji\\\",\\\"Segoe UI Emoji\\\"\",\"height\":\"100vh\",\"textAlign\":\"center\",\"display\":\"flex\",\"flexDirection\":\"column\",\"alignItems\":\"center\",\"justifyContent\":\"center\"},\"children\":[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"children\":[[\"$\",\"style\",null,{\"dangerouslySetInnerHTML\":{\"__html\":\"body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}\"}}],[\"$\",\"h1\",null,{\"className\":\"next-error-h1\",\"style\":{\"display\":\"inline-block\",\"margin\":\"0 20px 0 0\",\"padding\":\"0 23px 0 0\",\"fontSize\":24,\"fontWeight\":500,\"verticalAlign\":\"top\",\"lineHeight\":\"49px\"},\"children\":\"404\"}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"style\":{\"display\":\"inline-block\"},\"children\":[\"$\",\"h2\",null,{\"style\":{\"fontSize\":14,\"fontWeight\":400,\"lineHeight\":\"49px\",\"margin\":0},\"children\":\"This page could not be found.\"}]}]]}]}]],\"childProp\":{\"current\":[[\"$\",\"$La\",null,{\"params\":{},\"searchParams\":{}}],null,null,[]],\"segment\":\"\"}}]}]]}]]}],null,null,[[\"$\",\"link\",\"0\",{\"rel\":\"stylesheet\",\"href\":\"/_next/static/css/563c339e5aa1a520.css\",\"precedence\":\"next.js\"}]]]}]\n"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"3:[[[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"charSet\":\"utf-8\"}],[\"$\",\"title\",null,{\"children\":\"Work In Ed\"}],[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"name\":\"description\",\"content\":\"A new way to discover a job in teaching\"}],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"name\":\"viewport\",\"content\":\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"}],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]],[null,null,null,null],null,null,[null,null,null,null,null],null,[null,[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"property\":\"og:title\",\"content\":\"Work In Ed\"}],[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"property\":\"og:description\",\"content\":\"A new way to discover a job in teaching\"}],[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"property\":\"og:url\",\"content\":\"https://workined.org/\"}],null,null,null,null,[[[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"property\":\"og:image\",\"content\":\"https://d1lxsr6s25nfb5.cloudfront.net/images/38eb3e844473fb060c6901b74736910e.jpeg\"}]]],null,null,null,null,null,null,[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"property\":\"og:type\",\"content\":\"website\"}]],null,null,[null,[[\"$\",\"link\",null,{\"rel\":\"icon\",\"href\":\"/_next/static/media/metadata/favicon.603d046c.ico\",\"type\":\"image/x-icon\",\"sizes\":\"any\"}]],[],null]]\n"])</script>
</html>
```

Are there any special settings we need to use on the Vercel deployment side or on the NextJS application?